# How to plot solutions of system of nonlinear differential equations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am trying to follow this [research paper](http://mtbi.asu.edu/files/Evolution_of_within-host_Antibiotic_Resistance_in_Gonorrhea.pdf). I am trying to duplicate the graph of the solutions located in Figure 7 on page 20. I have a screenshot of Figure 7:[image]

I would first like to recreate the left picture. The system in question is what I have as `dX`. Here is what I have in an m-file:

```
function dX = CompetitionModel(t,X)       
  bs = 8*10^(-3); 
  bl = 4*10^(-3); 
  bh = 6.4*10^(-3);
  N = bs + bl + bh;
  K = 10^8;
  m1 = 2*10^(-5); 
  m2 = 9*10^(-9); 
  p = 5*10^(-13); 
  I = 10^(-3); 
  T = 0; 
  a = 0; 
  dX = [X(1) * (bs * (1 - N/K) - I - T - m1) - p * X(1) * (X(2) + X(3));
       X(2) * (bl * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T - m2) + m1 * X(1) + p * X(2) * (X(1) - X(3));
       X(3) * (bh * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T) + m2 * X(2) + p * X(3) * (X(1) + X(2))];
end
```

`ode45` has the syntax: `[T,Y] = solver(odefun,tspan,y0)`. I get the tspan from the picture I posted. My initial conditions are:`S0 = 10^4; Rl0 = 0; Rh0 = 0`, so this is what I have as `y0`. I type the following into the command window:

```
>>[t,X1] = ode45('CompetitionModel', [0,45000], [10^4, 0, 0]);
>>[t,X2] = ode45('CompetitionModel', [0,45000], [10^4, 0, 0]);
>>[t,X3] = ode45('CompetitionModel', [0,45000], [10^4, 0, 0]);
```

MATLAB has been busy for the past 30 minutes and my laptop is starting to get really hot. So I can't get to plotting until it's finished and I don't know if there are any errors in my code. I was wondering if there was perhaps a better way that I could get the solutions of the system `dX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the ODE against the paper and found one mistake. According to the last paragraph of page 9 in the paper, `N = S + Rl + Rh`. A corrected code:

```
function dX = CompetitionModel(~,X)       
  bs = 8e-3; 
  bl = 4e-3; 
  bh = 6.4e-3;
  N = sum(X);  % this line was incorrect
  K = 1e8;
  m1 = 2e-5; 
  m2 = 9e-9; 
  p = 5e-13; 
  I = 1e-3; 
  T = 0;
  a = 0; 
  dX = [X(1) * (bs * (1 - N/K) - I - T - m1) - p * X(1) * (X(2) + X(3));
       X(2) * (bl * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T - m2) + m1 * X(1) + p * X(2) * (X(1) - X(3));
       X(3) * (bh * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T) + m2 * X(2) + p * X(3) * (X(1) + X(2))];
```

Note a couple of syntactic changes. First, since you do not actually use the time value in your ODE, you can leave a `~` in place of the `t` that you had in your function definition as a stand-in for the unused input. Second, you can use the notation `8e-3` instead of `8*10^(-3)`. They evaluate to the same thing, but the former looks a little cleaner.

The plot for no treatment, i.e. `T = 0`, is shown below.

[image: No Treatment Population]

I figured out the issue in the ODE by first trying to solve your equation with some of the stiff ODE solvers in MATLAB. See the [MATLAB ODE solver documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html) for more details. Basically I solved it with `ode15s` and `ode23s` and found that the solution was unstable (population went off to infinity). These other solvers are good tools to keep in mind if your solution is hanging; sometimes one of the others will work and it will either give you what you want, or indicate that you have another problem somewhere else.

**Note:** I am fairly certain that you are not using "phase portrait" correctly here. You are just looking for the solution of the ODE with respect to time with a given set of initial conditions. A [phase portrait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait) looks at how the states of the system (your three different populations here) evolve given different sets of initial conditions. It does not show you anything about the time-dependence of these solutions, just how they evolve relative to one-another.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistakes. I guess I understand "phase portrait" as a plot of the the solution of the system of DEs. You have cleared up my confusion. Thanks a lot for your time.