# Plotting solutions to differential equations, but not with respect to time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

My question today is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816214/solved-how-to-plot-solutions-of-system-of-nonlinear-differential-equations-in). I am following this [research paper](http://mtbi.asu.edu/files/Evolution_of_within-host_Antibiotic_Resistance_in_Gonorrhea.pdf). I am trying to duplicate figure 8 located on page 20. I have a screenshot: [image]

I'm confused on how to plot the left figure this in MATLAB because now a instead of having time varying we have the treatment varying. Here's what I have from the previous question:

```
function dX = CompetitionModel(~,X)       
  bs = 8e-3; 
  bl = 4e-3; 
  bh = 6.4e-3;
  N = sum(X);  
  K = 1e8;
  m1 = 2e-5; 
  m2 = 9e-9; 
  p = 5e-13; 
  I = 1e-3; 
  T = 1e-3; % Treatment
  a = 0; 
  dX = [X(1) * (bs * (1 - N/K) - I - T - m1) - p * X(1) * (X(2) + X(3));
       X(2) * (bl * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T - m2) + m1 * X(1) + p * X(2) * (X(1) - X(3));
       X(3) * (bh * (1 - N/K) - I - a*T) + m2 * X(2) + p * X(3) * (X(1) + X(2))];
end
```

To plot my equations in the previous question, I typed the following in the command window:

```
>> [t,Y] = ode45(@CompetitionModel, [0 4.5e4], [1e4 0 0]);
>> plot(t,X(:,1), t,X(:,2), t,X(:,3))
```

In my function file, I have Treatment already defined. I'm guessing that it shouldn't be anymore. So  what can I do so that I have Treatment varying instead of time? I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still solve the equation in regards to the time - but solely plot the value at the time t = 1 month.
To vary the treatment you need an additional loop around the ode45 call and pass the current treatment-value to the function dX

```
for treatment = 10^-4:10^-5:10^-3
    [t,Y] = ode45(@CompetitionModel, [0 4.5e4], [1e4 0 0], [] , treatment);
    plot(treatment,Y(end,1), 'x')
    plot(treatment,Y(end,2), 'kx')
    plot(treatment,Y(end,3), 'rx')
    hold on
end
```

the function dX now has to be changed to accept the treatment input:

```
function dX = CompetitionModel(~,X, T)
```

Finally, comment your old treatment assignment in the function dX: %T = 1e-3; % Treatment

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am still unable to get my code functioning properly. I don't understand what you have in the [t,Y] line. You have added "[], treatment", why?

Comment: I don't understand how to plot the value at time=1 month still. Should I use the ones function to save as a vector?

Comment: thats a good question!  The position where i inserted the [] is reserved for "ode-options". Since i don't want to change any i use an empty list.  After the options i can specify the parameters that will be handed to the function

Comment: you can start by plotting solely the last result of the timeseries - plot(t,X(end,1),'x')

Comment: yep, around the ode45 call.   For every parametrisation you calculate the complete timeseries - but plot only the result of the last timestep (or at the timestep where t = 1 month).  Corrected plot command: plot(treatment ,X(end,1),'x')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57863/discussion-between-souled-outt-and-zinjaai).